# PHP Lumen - teste TDD Upload de Imagens não funciona no framework Lumen do PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, tdd, lumen

Estou tentando criar um método de teste para upload de imagens utilizando o framework (Lumen) do PHP. Porém estou tendo problemas com o seguinte método do UploadedFile: `$request->file('images')` isso sempre me retorna um valor `null`. abaixo o código:

```
public function testCreate() // função teste, executado com phpunit
{
    $token = $this->tokenGenerate();

    Storage::fake('products');

    factory(App\ProductImage::class)->make();
    $productImage = factory(\App\ProductImage::class)->create()->toArray();
    $this->seeInDatabase('product_images', $productImage);

    $file = new File(UploadedFile::fake()->create('image.jpg')); // aqui é onde está sendo criado um objeto do tipo UploadedFile e é enviado por post pela rota abaixo

    $this->post('/api/productImages', ['product_id' => $productImage['product_id'], 'images'=>$file], ['Authorization' => $token['access_token'], 'Content-Type' => 'multpart\formdata']);
    dd(json_decode($this->response->content()));
}
```

e esse é meu controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product_id = $request->product_id;
    $file = $request->file('images'); // não reconhece como file 'eu acho'

    dd($file); // sempre retorna null

    $fileName = $file->hashName();
    $url = $file->store('products');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade, eu precisei usar o call para como requisição para enviar um objeto do tipo `UploadedFile`

```
$file = UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg');

factory(App\ProductImage::class)->make();
$productImage = factory(\App\ProductImage::class)->create()->toArray();
$this->seeInDatabase('product_images', $productImage);

$server = ['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => 'Bearer ' . $token['access_token']];
$this->call(
    'POST',
    '/api/productImages', 
    ['product_id' => $productImage['product_id']], 
    [], 
    ['images' => $file], $server)
->json();
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o teu erro está ao setar o header `Content-Type`:

Invés de isto: `'Content-Type' => 'multpart\formdata'`

Tenta assim:
`'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'`